# Why moscato sweet?

Tags: wine, flavor, drinking

Recently I'm in love with Moscato wine. It is very sweet. Is it real wine? Attached is the brand I consumed. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Winemakers can make either a dry wine or sweet wine.

If the winemakers want to make a sweet wine, they must artificially halt the fermentation process by either increasing or decreasing the temperature in the fermentation tank to a certain level in which the yeasts cannot survive. Manipulating the temperature kills the yeast (well, actually they lay dormant) and it allows natural sugar to be left in the wine. The high sugar concentration of the grape plays a role, too.

There is a second way to artificially halt the fermentation process, it is called fortification. Winemakers will add alcohol during the fermentation process to a level in which the yeasts cannot survive, also leaving natural sugar in the wine.

And by the way, Moscato is purposefully made in a sweet style which is why it is always sweet.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your description of making sweet wine is wrong. There are several ways to make sweet wine. These are the methods: Late harvest picking where the grapes are too sweet to ferment completely, adding sugar or grape juice and then sterile filtering, adding sulfites (mutage) to kill the yeast, adding alcohol to kill the yeast. The most common these days is sterile filtering.

Raising the temperature to kill the yeast is rarely done since you will basically be cooking the wine.

Moscato is probably done through sterile filtering during fermentation and then artificially carbonated.

Answer (score 0):

Moscato is a sparkling white wine made in the Piedmont region of Italy. It is made with Muscat (Moscato) grapes. They are fermented naturally until they hit 5.5% ABV and then the wine is run through a sterile filter to preserve the sweetness and stop fermentation. It's then artificially carbonated and put in a bottle. It's meant to be an dessert wine because of this sweetness. Also known as [Moscato d'Asti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscato_d%27Asti) and there is a similar wine made nearby simply called Asti.

Comment: as far as I am aware, it's not artificially carbonated.

Comment: Maybe they are using the Charmat process but I doubt if they are doing méthode Champenoise in the bottle. They have to sterile filter it outside the bottle.